# Change resolution of VM through Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines, cicd, azure-pipelines-release-task

I'm trying to change screen resolution of a VM through Azure CI-CD pipeline using a powershell task.

The powershell task contains the below inline script to do this.

```
$script="/c SetResolution.exe 0 1 , 0 0 1920 1080"

#ResolutionPath is a Pipeline variable contins --> "Path\to\where\SetResolution.exe\is\present\in\VM" 

Invoke-VMScript -ScriptText { Set-Location "$(ResolutionPath)" } -VM $(VMhost) -GuestUser admin -GuestPassword "myPassword" 

Invoke-VMScript -ScriptText { cmd.exe $script } -VM $(VMhost) -GuestUser admin -GuestPassword "myPassword"
```

Now the above command i.e., `cmd.exe /c SetResolution.exe 0 1 , 0 0 1920 1080` works perfectly when executed locally in the VM. I can change the screen resolution to all available resolution in the VM display settings using the above command.

**Problem:** But the same command doesn't change the resolution when triggered through the pipeline. Though the task completes successfully without any errors.

Can anyone please help me with this? I have tried different ways. I have also tried to store the same command in a bat file (in the VM), so that I can run the bat file but it doesn't work either.